# Finite group with subgroup containing all its centralizers

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group. $H \leq G$. Suppose $\forall x \in H\backslash\{1\}, C_G(x) \subset H$. Prove that gcd$(|H|, [G:H]) = 1$.

This was a homework question from last semester that I'm trying to figure out since I didn't get it at the time.

The hint was to assume some prime $p \mid \gcd(|H|, [G:H])$. Then consider $Q \in Syl_p(H)$, and a corresponding $P \in Syl_p(G)$, s.t $Q \subset P$. Then show that $Z(P) \subset Q$. I've almost completed this part (I have $Z(P) \subset H$. But I don't know how to use the fact I'm looking for to complete the question.

Comment: Isn't it immediate from what you've done? Suppose $P$ has an element $x$ with $x \not\in H$. Any non-identity element in $Z(P)$ lies in $H$ and commutes with $x$, so its centralizer is not contained in $H$, contradiction. Therefore $P$ is contained in $H$, contradicting that $p$ divides $[G : H]$.

Comment: This is not a research level question, and it would be more suitable for math.stackexchange.

Comment: Note that $P\cap H= Q$, so if $Z(P)\subseteq H$, then $Z(P)=Z(P)\cap H \subseteq P\cap H = Q$.